# Выборка из mySQL в обратном направлении

Tags: php, mysql

Все привет!

Ка известно, через `mysql_fetch_array()` идет выборка записей с таблички с первой записи.
Есть какой-то способ сделать так, чтобы выборка шла не с первой записи, а с последней?

Comment: ORDER BY в запросе по нужному полю

Comment: Для этого записи надо получать в обратном направлении. Т.е. в запросе использовать что-то типа `ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: @Юрий Зав, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER BY "тут поле по которому сортировать" DESC

[MySQL man](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-4.0-ru/reference.html)

Comment: А можете на примере написать, напишите запрос полностью.

Comment: Разобрался, все работает отлично)